# Strings Received via BLE appear on multiple lines

Tags: string, bluetooth-lowenergy, lines

I am receiving strings from my peripheral fine but since the characteristics can only contain 20 bytes the data arrives in 3 loads. When adding this to a text field is no problem - it all appears in one line as desired but when I try to do things with this data it appears on multiple lines.

`func serialDidReceiveString(_ message: String) {
      mainTextView.text? += message
      let allData = message
      print(allData)`

The result is :

```
194a1886a19901a19998
a233441a232332a11234
12a34123412
```

Essentially I am trying to get his all of this into one line but I seem to have tried all the standard methods including trimming characters for blankspaces and newlines etc.. The only method that seemed to work was if I used :

```
print(allData, terminator: "")
```

This would appear as one line but only in the debugging console - not much use.

Any suggestions??

Comment: you can add something with your message which will define the end of that message. Concatenate all string and do something when the message end mark receive.

Comment: @Md.MostafizurRahmanMafi , please could you expand a little - how can you define the end of the message since the message is the ble characteristics which is changing??

Comment: you said, "I am receiving strings from my peripheral". so you can add something with the message which you send from peripheral to indicate end mark.

Comment: @Md.MostafizurRahmanMafi - ok I have defined the end of the message, but I am not able to concatenate the strings becaue when I try to define a range of the number of characters in the string it does the range on every line, I am not able to isolate a single line.